# How can I get more than one document from mongodb with fastapi?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, fastapi

my db model looks like this...

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Store(BaseModel):
    name: str
    store_code : str
```

and there can be same store names in db with different store_code.
what I want is filtering all informations of stores with same names.
for example, if my db is like this...

```
{
name:lg
store_code: 123

name:lg
store_code:456
}
```

I'd like to see all those two documents
my python fast api code is like this..

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from database import *
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/api/store{store_name}", response_model=Store)
async def get_store_by_name(store_name):
    response = await fetch_store_by_name(store_name)
    if response:
        return response
    raise HTTPException
```

and this is my mongo query code...

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from model import Store

client = MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)


database = client.store

async def fetch_store_by_name(store_name:str):
    document = collection.find({"name":store_name})
    return document
```

i thought in the document, there would be two documents eventually.
but there's always an error like this

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Store
response
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

is there anyone to help me please?

++++

I just changed my query like this

```
async def fetch_store_by_name(store_name:str):
    stores = []
    cursor = collection.find({"name":store_name})
    for document in cursor:
        stores.append(document)
    return stores
```

this should returns two documents like I expected but it still has

```
ValueError: [TypeError("'ObjectId' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

this error.

I think my fast-api code has a problem which I really have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

```
async def fetch_store_by_name(store_name:str):
stores = []  ---Fault in this line---  
cursor = collection.find({"name":store_name})
for document in cursor:
    stores.append(document)
return stores
```

stores should be a string value, not a list as Mongodb will try to find it as the default value that you provided. In this case - str